# Why ViewBag if condition not working in Jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get a check ViewBag in jquery. It seems its working. I have added `console.log` and `alert` both not working. Whats wrong in my code?

```
     /* Begin- Here we check if member credit card blocked */
        bool isCCBlocked = membershipRenewal.CheckCCDeniedDemographic(memberId);
        ViewBag.IsCCBlocked = isCCBlocked?"true":"false";
     /* End- Here we check if member credit card blocked */
```

JQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        // Checking if member credit card blocked    
        if (@ViewBag.IsCCBlocked.ToString().ToLower()==="true") {
            alert("IsCCBlocked");
        }
});
```

Comment: You just missed quotation marks. Try this `if ("@ViewBag.IsCCBlocked?.ToString()?.ToLower()" === "true") {`

Comment: or what about just `if (@ViewBag.IsCCBlocked.ToString().ToLower())`?  I.e. `if(true)`

Comment: With these kinds of problems, step 1 is _always_ to `View Source` in the browser.

Comment: Try this:  if ('@ViewBag.IsCCBlocked'=='True') {
            alert("IsCCBlocked");
        }

Answer (score 3):

You can include server side code in a .cshtml file... the server side code has to be preceded by `@` symbol... when you run the program, the server side code is executed on the server and then the page is rendered into an HTML file which is sent to the client...

Since you are converting the content of the `@ViewBag` into string, you need to put it in quotes (because strings are quoted in .js), so you need something like this:

```
// this will generate something like: var isCCBlocked = 'true'; 
var isCCBlocked = '@ViewBag.IsCCBlocked.ToString().ToLower()'; 
if (isCcBlocked === "true") {
    alert("IsCCBlocked");
}
```